# Eager load ALL by default with Entity Framework within a Generic Repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I am currently implementing the repository pattern which allows me to pass my class and context into a general repository. This is working perfectly. The methods I am interested in are Get and Find. The find allows me to specify and "order", some "where" statements and some "include" statements. This is ideal.

```
public class GeneralRepository<TEntity> : IGeneralRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{

    readonly GamesContext context;
    readonly DbSet<TEntity> db;

    public GeneralRepository(GamesContext existingContext)
    {
        context = existingContext;
        db = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public TEntity Get(object id)
    {
        return db.Find(id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = db;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
           (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
           return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
           return query.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

My question however, when I use the Get method I would rather it return the full object graph. Lazy loading is turned off at the moment but to eager load I need to add the relevant includes, only this would defeat the object of doing a generic repository.

I know I could just use the find method however it would be much quicker to by default return all related data using the get method.

Any ideas how I can get all (eager load all) by default?

thanks.

Comment: Eager loading of all related objects can load whole database with single entity you are getting

Comment: The current Get method above only returns the entity within that DbSet... I require the relational DbSet's. Cheers.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Note that with proper aggregate design (such as is customary in DDD, for example), eagerly loading complete object graphs is a great advantage and certainly will not load the entire database. I consider this a very valuable question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bad idea. Especially if you plan to build the application further. This is a road to performance bottlenecks and OutOfMemory exceptions.

And I found that generic repositories are also anti-pattern. With time you'll realise that you'll need to add more and more functions within that `Get` method and eventually it will just copy implementation of `DbContext`.

In fact, your current implementation does not serve any purpose of isolation. Why not just use DbContext directly?

I recommend dump the idea of Generic stuff and have small Query classes that retrieve only the entities you require in a controlled fashion, not everything for everyone. Have a look at [this](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) .

And to answer your question, Entity Framework does not have an option to provide `IncludeAll`. You can do a hack with reflection, but I'm not going to give solution here because it is just a bad practice.

Comment: It's a very good raised. I have separate inherited repositories for when more complex operations are needed. Thanks for the clarification, a hack is not needed. I can continue to use the find method. Using the dbContext is not really possible, I am using UnitOfWork and the General Repository, unitOfWork is called from the services, I am trying to keep it as dynamic as possible and trying to maximize code re-use.

Comment: "Why not just use DbContext directly?"  A thin layer can be useful for tests (you can have an alternate implementation of your repository for test purposes).

Comment: @emodendroket With time I found that replacing repositories just for tests is also quite bad - like that you are testing internal implementation, not the behavior. One small change in implementation (add `.Include(p => p.ProductType)` into actual repository) and your tests with mocked-repositories will fail with null-reference exceptions. These days I prefer using actual DB for testing and not replace DbContext for tests.

Comment: Well, I'm assuming what you're interested in really testing is not the repository itself but something else.

Comment: @emodendroket yes, this is case-by case decision. What I'm saying that integration tests are not that bad. And if testing access to DB, use the actual DB, not mocks of DB.

Comment: Link provided in the answer is no more available. Please update the link as I believe it would be very useful. Thanks

Comment: @developer Link works for me. Links to "On Query Side of my architecture" article by Steven

Comment: yes, it's working now, might went down for a while. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here is a a good aproach to eager load just what you need using a generic repository pattern. Hope it can help someone, it's easy to use and simple enough to include in your code.

IRepository.cs:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] properties);
}
```

Repository.cs

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{    
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbset;

    public Repository(DbSet<TEntity> dbset)
    {
        _dbset = dbset;
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] properties)
    {  
        if (properties == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(properties));

        var query = _dbset as IQueryable<TEntity>; // _dbSet = dbContext.Set<TEntity>()

        query = properties
                   .Aggregate(query, (current, property) => current.Include(property));

        return query.AsNoTracking().ToList(); //readonly
    }
}
```

Some model to explain how to use:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<Address> Address {get; set;}
    public List<Cart> Carts {get; set;}
}
```

How to use:

```
var repository = new Repository<User>();
var users = repository.GetAll(d => d.Address, d => d.Carts);
```

Ref: [Link](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/05/30/generic-dal-using-entity-framework/)

Comment: Based on your example, the parameter `properties` in method `GetAll` needs the **params** keyword.

Comment: Looks good for first level entities, any ideas on how to implement ```.ThenInclude()``` for many-to-many?